# Terraform accessing list elements from module output

Tags: terraform

Let's say I have a module, which generates some ids:
**module.tf:**

```
resource "random_id" "etcdapiserver-id" {
  byte_length         = 4
  count               = "${var.etcd_apiserver_count}"
}
```

**module_output.tf:**

```
output "etcdapiserver_hostname_list" {
  value = ["${random_id.etcdapiserver-id.*.hex}"]
}
```

It seems to work fine and the list ends up in the output successfully:

```
terraform output --module=module

etcdapiserver_hostname_list = [
    751adf6a,
    9e573ee7,
    edb94de3
]
```

Now I want to use elements from this list in main terraform config. Let's say I'm creating several compute instances on openstack:
**main.tf:**

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "etcdapiserver" {
  count   = "3"
  name    = "etcdapi-node-${element(module.ignition.etcdapiserver_hostname_list.*, count.index)}"
```

But it would fail with

> Error: resource 'openstack_compute_instance_v2.etcdapiserver' config:
>   "etcdapiserver_hostname_list.*" is not a valid output for module
>   "ignition"

Is there any way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Terraform contributor answered my question on GitHub.

> The general syntax for accessing the element of a list is list[index].
>   In your case, that would be something like
>   module.ignition.etcdapiserver_hostname_list[count.index].